# Why isn't ContentSettings cache_control max-age being honored in Azure storage blob via Python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, cache-control, azure-python-sdk

I can't seem to activate Cache-Control `max-age` in an Azure storage blob in Python via the following code:

```
 contentSettings = ContentSettings(cache_control="max-age=86400")  
 containerClient.upload_blob(blobname, theBytes, length=byteCount, 
        overwrite=True, content_settings=contentSettings)
```

In the web based Azure storage browser, it appears `max-age` is correctly set:
[image: Azure storage browser]

However, `max-age` doesn't seem to be propagated to a browser client when the blob is downloaded.  The file is downloaded correctly but is never cached in the client.  If it matters, I'm using to axios to retrieve the file:

```
axios.get(url, { responseType: "arraybuffer" })...
```

Here's the chrome developer network view of the file.  Notice `max-age` is missing:

[image: Chrome]

One other oddity:  The Azure doc for `ContentSettings` contains the phrase:
*If the cache_control has previously been set for the blob, that value is stored.* Which means what exactly?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for this could be the CORS settings which is preventing response headers being exposed to the client.

Please check the `Exposed Headers` CORS settings for blob service on the storage account and make sure all `x-ms-*` response headers are exposed.

You can also try by setting `*` (i.e. all response headers) for exposed header CORS setting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion Gaurav.  It turned out the problem was (as is usually the case) my own stupidity.  I was fetching the file via an ASP.net core controller/service and this wasn't propagating the `Etag` and `Cache-Control` values fetched from the Azure blob.

It seems curious there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this.  All of the Azure blob ASP.net core examples I found manually copy over the individual blob properties rather than automatically propagating them.